# Timezone conversion not working on my server

Tags: php, timezone

This PHP code is supposed to convert an Australia/Sydney datetime to UTC. It doesn't work. The resulting datetime is unconverted:

```
$local_datetime = "2018-04-11 16:01:48";
echo "Local datetime: $local_datetime<br>";

$local_timezone = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Sydney');
$datetime = new DateTime($local_datetime, $local_timezone);

$utc_timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$datetime->setTimeZone($utc_timezone);

$utc_datetime = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "UTC datetime: $utc_datetime";
```

The output is:

```
Local datetime: 2018-04-11 16:01:48  
UTC datetime: 2018-04-11 16:01:48
```

I tried the code at phptester.net and got the correct results:

```
Local datetime: 2018-04-11 16:01:48  
UTC datetime: 2018-04-11 06:01:48
```

I've also used checked my timezone names with this:

```
DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);
```

Both 'Australia/Sydney' and 'UTC' were on the list.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

---

EDIT - It seems that specifying "UTC" as the timezone in this command is the problem:

```
$utc_timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC')
```

If I change it to

```
$utc_timezone = new DateTimeZone('Atlantic/Reykjavik');
```

Then I get the correct conversion into Iceland time, which is the same as UTC:

```
Local datetime: 2018-04-11 16:01:48  
UTC datetime: 2018-04-11 06:01:48
```

I still don't know why "UTC" doesn't work on my server. But "Atlantic/Reykjavik" is a workaround.

Comment: This should indeed work as is…

Comment: Do you really set a static value for "$local_datetime" or is it just for the demo?

Comment: Do you have a global timezone set? Sometimes PHP is bit bitchy if there is no timezone configured for the current machine. Does `date_default_timezone_get()` yield some result? See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @OfirBaruch The static value is just for debugging purposes.

Comment: @feeela date_default_timezone_get() returns "Australia/Sydney"

Comment: and the dynamic value is in that date structure or is it a unix timestamp?

Comment: @OfirBaruch The dynamic value is exactly as shown in this example. But it's not the date format that's the problem. It appears that "UTC" is not recognised as a valid DateTimeZone on my server.